# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.kinvey:android-sdk:v4.3.2

Tags: java, android

I followed the steps for installing the kinvey dependencies from their site  (https://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/getting-started) and got an error as follows:

ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.kinvey:android-sdk:v4.3.2

I didn't find any solution for that, hope you can help :)

Thanks,

Ofer

```
implementation ('com.github.kinvey:android-sdk:v4.3.2') {
    exclude(module: 'guava-jdk5')
}
```

ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.kinvey:android-sdk:v4.3.2
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Answer (score 0):

Please read all documentation from your url!

[Url is here](https://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/getting-started), and follow the instructions:

1. Download the latest Kinvey library (zip) and extract the downloaded zip file.
2. In Android Studio, right click on your project and select Reveal In
   Finder (OSX) or Reveal in Explorer (Windows).
3. In the window that opens, navigate to the app/libs directory.
4. If the libs directory does not exist, create it.
5. **Copy all JAR and AAR files from the lib/ folder of the extracted
   Kinvey library zip to the app/libs folder you opened in the previous
   step.**